# How to flatten and reduce array with objects to comma separated strings in javascript (ionic | Angular | NodeJS | MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mongodb, ionic-framework

I have this array from an API:

```
let passions = [
{_id: "60a1557f0b4f226732c4597c",name: "Netflix"},
{_id: "60a1557f0b4f226732c4597b",name: "Movies"}
]
```

I would like to return exactly the following array:

```
['60a1557f0b4f226732c4597c', '60a1557f0b4f226732c4597b']
```

My code:

```
for(var key in passions){
return key._id
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple map function should be enough to fix this issue for you.

```
const extractedIds = passions.map((e) => e._id);
```

The .map function applies that given function (in this case the function is (e) => e.["_id"]) to each element of your array and returns an array of the results. This means that it's going to return out a new array in the way you're hoping.

[Live repl of this in action](https://replit.com/@saintjustin/HandyShamelessAcrobat)

Answer (score 0):

```
const passionIDs = passions.reduce((acc, next) => {
  acc.push(next._id);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

checkout [`reduce` function in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)